# Missing role permissions on the request even though it is added

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am testing sending activity feed notifications to users.

I have configured my app in Azure AD app registrations to have delegated permission: TeamsActivity.Send

I first obtain auth token by calling:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

with client_id, client_secret, scope = https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, and grant_type = client_credentials

I then call activity feed notification endpoint: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/teamwork/sendActivityNotification](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserId%7D/teamwork/sendActivityNotification) with the auth token as part of Authorization: Bearer {authToken} header.

However, I am getting the following error:

"Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'TeamsActivity.Send'. Roles on the request ''."

May someone help with this? I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different types of permissions

- Delegated (scope)
- Application (role)

Take a look at the `TeamsActivity.Send` permission from the [MS Graph reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#teams-activity-permissions).

| Permission | Type | Display String | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TeamsActivity.Send | Delegated | Send a teamwork activity **as the user** | Allows the app to create new notifications in users' teamwork activity feeds **on behalf of the signed in user**. These notifications may not be discoverable or be held or governed by compliance policies. |
| TeamsActivity.Send | Application | Send a teamwork activity **to any user** | Allows the app to create new notifications in users' teamwork activity feeds **without a signed in user**. These notifications may not be discoverable or be held or governed by compliance policies. |

See the difference? `Delegated` permission requires a user to be logged into the application, and the application will send a message on behalf of the user (as the user). `Application` permission will send the message on behalf of the application (as itself).

You're using the `client_credentials` flow, which is a non-interactive flow. You can't use `delegated` permissions because there is no user signed-in.

You need to assign the same `TeamsActivity.Send` permission, but of the `Application` type instead, and grant admin consent for this permission as well.

**Reference**

[Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow - Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions)

[Introduction to permissions and consent - Types of permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview#types-of-permissions)